# Is it possible to reference values from the parents, parent Model?

Tags: sequelize.js

Lets assume the following tables `author`,`posts`,`comments`.

the connection between the tables is as follows:

```
AuthorModel.hasMany(PostModel);
PostModel.belongsTo(AuthorModel);
PostModel.hasMany(CommentModel);
CommentModel.belongsTo(PostModel);
```

When I want to select all specific comments and the authors name of the post, which is stored in the table `author` only. Do I really need to do it like this?:

```
Comment.findAll({
            attributes: ["text"],
            include: [{
                model: Post, attributes: [''], include: [{
                    model: Author, attributes: ['name']
                }]
            }]
        })
```

That means, do I need to include the `Post` model, which then allows me to include the right `Author` model, which then allows me to select the authors name.

Or is it somehow possible to shorten this and reference the name of the author of the specific post from the Comment model?

Comment: You can find the post including comment and author at the same level, also you can if you need this often create a scope for it

Comment: how can I find them at the same level?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the post including comment and author at the same level, also you can if you need this often create a scope for it

```
Post.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: Author
             },{
                model: Comment
             }]
        })
```

Comment: That will give me all Posts including their Authors and Comments, but I want only the comments and the author of the post that has received the comments... sorry for the delay, just came back to this now